# When creating shape background programmatically, how to set stroke color using android.graphics.Color?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-drawable, android-color

I have a function which creates a shape programmatically using android.graphics.Color for stroke color as;

```
GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);        
shape.setStroke(3, borderColor);
```

The second argument of setStroke takes a ColorStateList. 
**How can I convert Color to ColorStateList?**

I tried creating one programmatically as;

```
int[][] states = new int[][] {
    new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
    new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
    new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
    new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed
};

int[] colors = new int[] {
    Color.toARGB(),
    Color.toARGB(),
    Color.toARGB(),
    Color.toARGB(),
};

ColorStateList myList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
```

But this is not working. How can I set stroke color from android.graphics.Color?

SOLVED:
setStroke was taking Color argument. There was problem in some other part of my code.

Comment: use `setStroke(int width, int color)`

Comment: @pskink setStorke does not have int as second parameter.

Comment: yes, it has, it was added in API level 1

Comment: @pskink I am using Xamarin. Maybe SetStroke with int parameter is not implemented in Xamarin? It shows error if I try to pass int color.

Comment: have you read documentation ? https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Graphics.Drawables.GradientDrawable/

Comment: @pskink Thanks, I solved the issue. setStroke was taking Color argument. There was problem in some other part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

ColorStateLists are created from XML resource files defined in the "color" subdirectory directory of an application's resource directory. The XML file contains a single "selector" element with a number of "item" elements inside. For example:

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:color="@color/sample_focused" />
   <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:state_enabled="false"
           android:color="@color/sample_disabled_pressed" />
   <item android:state_enabled="false"
           android:color="@color/sample_disabled_not_pressed" />
   <item android:color="@color/sample_default" />
 </selector>
```

This defines a set of state spec / color pairs where each state spec specifies a set of states that a view must either be in or not be in and the color specifies the color associated with that spec.